# Need help in Power BI Data Cleaning

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, data-cleaning

My goal is to clean the data and separate all 3 letter words and 2 letter words. The data is very messy because every row is different but there is something common (3 letter words and 2 letter words) these are code I want to extract: example of the result I want is:

```
1. ABC XY DEF YZ GHI WX
2. XYZ AB ZXY
```

format should be alternating from 3 letters and 2 letters

I need help in functions in extracting specifically the 3 letter words and 2 letter words in this format but I do not know what to do I have tried my best.

Thank you in advance for the help! [screencap of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7SA8.png)

I tried separating by delimiters. I'm expecting a function that would extract my goal data and format.

Comment: Your expected results show no relation to your data. Please clarify how it is derived from your data. Also do **NOT** post your data as a screenshot. It cannot be easily copy/pasted into a worksheet. One can try an OCR program, or manually enter it. Having to do either of these is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Answer (score 0):

Use Text.SplitAny and add any characters you may want to split by. Then use List.RemoveItems to remove extra blanks.

You can add custom column with formula below

```
List.RemoveItems(Text.SplitAny([Column1], " -/.0123456789"),{""})
```

Now expand the list column however you want.